# Is There an LL(k) Grammar for PCF?

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

We're working on top-down parsing in a compiler design class. Examples are all java-like languages. I decided to try a simple functional language to make it interesting so I went with PCF ([see e.g. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Computable_Functions)). I can't seem to get it into an LL(1) grammar, though. I think the issue is function application (i.e. juxtaposition of two expressions). I'm not getting clear answers on how to determine if it's just my lack of skill or if this is a language for which there is no LL(1) grammar, or LL(k) for that matter. Can someone clarify if I just need to be more clever or if there simply doesn't exist such a grammar?

Basically, my version of PCF is something like the below sketch (upper case are non-terminals, "//" starts comment). I say "something like" because I am not wedded to exactly this and I have written up many variants -- just want a reasonable variant of PCF.

Note that I have tried left-factoring and accounting for precedence with intermediate non-terminals.

```
Exp -> Const     // integer and boolean literals, normal ops e.g. +
    |  if Exp then Exp else Exp
    |  lambda identifier dot Exp    //lambda (function) abstraction
    |  Exp Exp                      // function application
    |  fix Exp                      // fixpoint operator (recursion)
```

Comment: This is standard left recursion elimination, see [here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT4.1.2.html) for example. The fundamental idea is that the grammar `A -> A α | β` is equivalent to `A -> β A';   A' -> ε | α A'`. You have to generalize to the case with more `β`s.

Comment: @Bakuriu I did try to eliminate left recursion, but perhaps I only did so for *direct* left recursion. I'll have to take another look at your link regarding the indirect part. However, that link does say something about messing up the associativity, which I was also struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is left-recursive, which does not play well with top-down parsers, as described by LL(k).

Specifically, trying to parse an `Exp` leads to trying to first parse the first part of a function application `Exp Exp`... which, for a top-down parser, makes an infinite loop.

The likely solution in your case would be to implement an arbitrary-length function application in a right-recursive style:

```
AppExp -> Exp | Exp AppExp

Exp -> Const | (AppExp) | ...
```

Note that this construction removes a grammar ambiguity.  Unfortunately, it resolves it in the wrong direction for your problem -- and there is no nice way to fix it;  a left-associative version:

```
AppExp  -> Exp | AppExp Exp
```

will be just as left-recursive as the original.

The (not-so-nice) way to fix this within the scope of a top-down parser is to accept the right-associative grammar, treat `AppExp` as a list, and reverse it after parsing so that your abstract syntax tree has the associativity you want:

```
 application expression:    f a b c d
   |
   |  LL(1) parse
   v
 right-associative   --->   left-associative
       @             list              @
      / \          reversal           / \
     f   @                           @   d
        / \                         / \
       a   @                       @   c
          / \                     / \
         b   @                   @   b
            / \                 / \
           c   .               .   a
               |               |
               d               f
```

Combinator parser libraries like Parsec typically have conveniently pre-packaged features that will do this for you.

In language-theoretic terms, this demonstrates the distinction between the *language* accepted by a grammar, and a *parsing* produced by a parser based on that grammar....

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I am aware that the example grammar is directly left-recursive, and I tried to remove the left recursion (and handle precedence and associativity of all the operators) with some grammars that ended up *much* larger. However, I think they are still not LL(1) (indirectly left recursive on the application?). I was trying to understand whether I was simply barking up the wrong tree. I *think* perhaps that is what you are saying -- give up on LL(1) and do it a different way -- but I'll have to digest your answer when I have some time.

Comment: My answer recommends a way to stick with LL(1) and work with what a top-down parser can give you.  I do suspect that you were barking up the wrong tree, but the lesson to learn here is that, for cases like this, left-recursion elimination will mangle your parse order no matter how you try to slice it.

Comment: To put it another way:  you *can* make an LL(1) grammar that will recognize your language; my answer shows you an example.  However, your comment suggests that you *also* want your grammar to parse your application syntax in a left-associative way, which won't work for LL(1), or for pretty much any kind of top-down parser short of a fully-general one.

Comment: So, the method I recommend (particularly since your class is working on the top-down parsing chapter) is to go with an LL(1) grammar that recognizes your language (even though it doesn't parse it in the order you want), and fix the parse ordering *afterwards*.

Comment: Thank you again for you elaboration. I'll be looking at this some more. Perhaps one place I was getting lost is that the instructor seems to be conflating the two ideas you are separating. I *think* the instructor would say that an LL(1) grammar for PCF would be *incorrect*, regardless of what language it accepted, if it led to a parse tree / AST that didn't reflect the correct/desired associativity without accommodations outside the grammar. We haven't done anything like having an extra step after the top-down parse to make extra-grammatical corrections.

Comment: Added some ascii art to demonstrate the association-reversal thing.